# Input value into define method

Tags: objective-c, macros

Get confusing define methods below

```
#define SELF_PASSWORD @"0"
#define SELF_DROPBOX @"1"
#define SELF_ABOUT @"2"

#define SELF_TABLE_TITLE_PASSWORD @"Password"
#define SELF_TABLE_TITLE_DROPBOX @"Dropbox"
#define SELF_TABLE_TITLE_ABOUT @"About"

#define SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(SECTION) = SECTION==SELF_PASSWORD?    SELF_TABLE_TITLE_PASSWORD:SECTION==SELF_DROPBOX?SELF_TABLE_TITLE_DROPBOX:SELF_TABLE_TITLE_ABOUT
-(void)buttonActionPassword:(UIButton *){
    NSLog(@“Title : %@”, SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(SELF_PASSWORD));
}

-(void)buttonActionAbout:(UIButton *){
    NSLog(@“Title : %@”, SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(SELF_ABOUT));
}
```

can we use **`SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(SELF_PASSWORD)`** method? 
Xcode error says ‘Expected expression’ what is that issue?

Comment: what you try to do in  SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(SECTION)

Comment: your condition totally wrong

Comment: @iDev how to get input value into define method? Eg: SELF_PASSWORD value is 0 NSLog should be display "Password". is possible input value in define method?

Comment: Why not write a method instead of this eye-bleeding DEFINE nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed,

**#define SELF_TABLE_HEADER_TITLE(key) [key isEqual:SELF_PASSWORD]?SELF_TABLE_TITLE_PASSWORD:[key isEqual:SELF_DROPBOX]?SELF_TABLE_TITLE_DROPBOX:SELF_TABLE_TITLE_ABOUT;**

"**==**" is not work. working use **isEqual** function.